# Angular 4: Observable not working

Tags: angular, observable

The application I'm working implements Azure Active Directory authorization through an adal.js port for Angular 2+, which works perfectly.

We have an `AuthenticationGuard` that handles the calls to/from our own `AdalService`. The `AdalService` has a function `ensureAuthenticatedAsync` which checks whether the user is logged in and if not, redirects him to the AD login page.

We now have the new requirement to be able to alternatively sign in with a custom generated token without when no AD account is available. After some modifications, my code looks like this:

**authentication.guard.ts**

```js
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean {
    ...
    let params = route.queryParams;
    let token = (params !== null && params['token'] !== undefined) ? params['token'] : null;

    this.adalService.ensureAuthenticatedAsync(token);
    ...
    return true;
}
```

**adal.service.ts**

```js
private context: adal.AuthenticationContext;

public ensureAuthenticatedAsync(token: string | null = null) {
    console.log('ensureAuthenticatedAsync', token);
    this.isAuthenticated.subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            console.log('not authenticated);
            if (token === null) {
                // forward to AAD login page -> this works perfectly
                this.context.login();
            } else {
                ...
                console.log('accessToken before', this.accessToken);
                this.customToken = token;
                console.log('accessToken after', this.accessToken);
                ...
            }
        }
    });
}

public get accessToken(): string {
    console.log('customToken in get accessToken', this.customToken);
    return (this.customToken === null) ? this.context.getCachedToken(this.adalClientId) : this.customToken;
}

public get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('accessToken in get isAuthenticated', this.accessToken);
    let isAuthenticated: boolean = (this.accessToken !== null);
    return Observable.of(isAuthenticated);
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.adalService.isAuthenticated.subscribe(isAuthenticated => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            // do some stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

**app.routes.ts**

```js
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
    { path: 'Access-Denied', component: AccessDeniedComponent }
];
```

This is what's logged in the console:

```
authentication guard  
customToken in get accessToken null  
accessToken in get isAuthenticated null  
customToken in get accessToken null  
ensureAuthenticatedAsync 12345  
not authenticated  
customToken in get accessToken null  
accessToken before null  
customToken in get accessToken 12345  
accessToken after 12345  
customToken in get accessToken 12345
```

Accessing the page regularly (http://localhost:3000/Dashboard) correctly triggers a redirect to the AD login page, which then returns to my application after login. There, the cacheed AD token is changed and isAuthenticated is triggered wherever it is subscribed to (in my case in `app.component.ts` ).

However, accessing the page using a token (http://localhost:3000/Dashboard/?token=12345) does not work. Even though `customToken` is modified with the value in the param, changes don't seem to be propagated and isAuthenticated stays `false` in the subscription(s).

Did I miss something?

Comment: could you add the relevant code of you app.component.ts and an example of how the customToken is modified? btw it seems weird that isAuthenticated return an observable<boolean> since there is no asynchronous task in it.

Comment: I have added the code from app.component.ts where I subscribe to the property. customToken is modified in adal.service.ts (this.customToken = token).

Comment: AS for the observable: I had a simple boolean property before that, and it was not refreshing the value when coming back from the adal login. I tried with an observable and that worked.

Comment: could you add your route configuration and an exemple of route with a custom token to understand how the authentication guard is called ?

Comment: I have added an example of two entries in my app.routes.ts, one with and the other without the AuthenticationGuard. Also, I changed the description in the end to add more details, including the route examples.

Comment: Your canActivate method doesn't return anything. I stopped reading at that point.

Comment: sorry for so many comment, but as your AuthenticationGuard.canActivate return nothing, it could be a race condition problem with your isAuthenticated getter which return and asynchronous observable. Have you try putting console.log just before this.customToken = token; and in isAuthenticated() ? Just to ensure that that your logic is played in the right order ?

Comment: actually, it does return something, it just went lost while shortening for SO as there is some other logic which is not relevant to the question. and yes, I tried logging at several points and it seems like everything is played in the right order, that's what is confusing. @JBNizet no need for the attitude...

Comment: What attitude? I just said I stopped reading because there might be some other errors, but I didn't go further. If you want help with your code, post your code. Not some other code, exhibiting different bugs. Now your guard always returns true, although the navigation shouldn't be accepted by the guard.

Comment: then I'm sorry for misunderstanding. It *is* my code, I just removed stuff that should not necessarily be posted in public. That's where I messed up. I have added the re-added the return to the code, though. The thing about always returning true: when I get a custom token, it's supposed to be true, always. Otherwise, you're redirected to the AAD login, which ensures that you're logged in, otherwise you have no business in the application. that's why it's always true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is about the guard localization.

Your guard is on /Dashboard route. So if you load only http://localhost:3000/?token=12345 your AuthenticationGuard is not called, thus ensureAuthenticatedAsync is not called either. So you have no redirection and not update of customToken in adal.service.ts.

If you want to use the computed result of you guard in appComponent you must use the guard on the route "leading" to appComponent

EDIT : 
The problem is that you misunderstand the reactive behavior. the way isAuthenticated is implemented it will emit a boolean one time and then complete. So your subscription in app.component will trigger only once.

What you are looking for is behavior subject, where you could "push" new data when needed or when customToken change.

Comment: That's a missunderstanding, actually any unmatched routes are redirected to /Dashboard. I have added some console.logs to the code in my question, to show you what I tried and what it actually outputs. You can see that it is actually updated, but isAuthorized is not triggered and the subscription in app.component.ts does not know that something happened.

Comment: Thanks for that! This actually helped. I switched to BehaviorSubject and this did the job.

Comment: sorry, I just didn't know how since the actual answer is in the comments. I marked your answer as correct one though, since that's how we got to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

in your **adal.service.ts** :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
...
public get isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
 let isAuthenticated: boolean = (this.accessToken !== null);
 return of(isAuthenticated);
}
```

Comment: would you mind explaining what difference that should make? What is different in `return of(isAuthenticated)` instead of `return Observable.of(isAuthenticated)` ?

Comment: The separate use of rxjs libraries makes it possible to optimize the prod build by using only what is necessary.

Comment: We would need more information to debug this script.